# In Jmeter , Cannot gracefully Shutdown through Batch file FUNCTION?

Tags: jmeter

I am using *Jmeter 5.5*.

I have created batch file for executing the test in NON GUI Mode.

Everything seems to be working fine .

In that batch file, I have written function for **shutdown**

I've tried these types of Functions, but don't seem to be working:-

1. `java -cp "%~dp0ApacheJMeter.jar" org.apache.jmeter.util.ShutdownClient Shutdown %*`
2. `java -cp %~dp0ApacheJMeter.jar org.apache.jmeter.util.ShutdownClient Shutdown %*`

***Error:-***
Getting error message like "could not find mainclass or ApacheJMeter"

Thanks,
Yazhdevi S

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to "create" or "write" the batch file or function as it's there already, check out [shutdown.cmd](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/shutdown.cmd) file (it lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

The point is that the function needs to be called from the directory where `ApacheJMeter.jar` file is, if it will be not there - the function call will fail.

If you have `ApacheJMeter.jar` in the current folder try using the following command:

```
java -cp ApacheJMeter.jar org.apache.jmeter.util.ShutdownClient Shutdown 4445
```

If you don't have either `shutdown.cmd` or `ApacheJMeter.jar` files in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation it means that your JMeter setup got corrupt somewhere somehow so I would suggest [reinstalling JMeter from scratch](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)

Comment: Hi Team,

IN my bin folder ,shutdown.cmd and ApacheJMeter.jar files both are available.

i have used following function "java -cp ApacheJMeter.jar org.apache.jmeter.util.ShutdownClient Shutdown 4445" (Which is sent by Dmitri T)

Below lines came in CMD the but not happening shutdown OPRATION
1 ) Sending Shutdown request to port 4445
2 ) Press any key to continue . . .

Thanks,
Yazhdevi S

Comment: ,Answer please for above comment ? @Dmitri T